# Reading a stringlist from a resource file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm using Delphi XE Starter. I've created a CCs.RC file and added that file to the project. A typical line in my CCs.RC file looks like this:

```
Danish1cc Text Danish1.cc
```

Directly after an Implementation line I've added

```
{$R CCs}
```

When I try to read this file into an existing stringlist, I get an `[EResNotFound][1]` error message. Here's the code I've used to try and read the file:

```
procedure LoadStringListFromResource(const ResName: string;SL : TStringList);
var
  RS: TResourceStream;
begin
  RS := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResName, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    SL.LoadFromStream(RS);
  finally
    RS.Free;
  end;
end;
///
LoadStringListFromResource('Danish1cc',MySL)
```

My goal is to embed the file in my EXE and of course be able to read it :) Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your resource's type doesn't match. In your *.RC file you use `TEXT` whereas in your code you use `RCDATA`.
You must either change your *.RC file to

```
Danish1cc RCDATA Danish1.cc
```

Or you must change

```
RS := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResName, RT_RCDATA);
```

to

```
RS := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResName, 'Text');
```

Comment: Yes, and here's the relevant documentation: [Resource-Definition Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line - `{$R CCs}`

You have compiled a resource file, isnt that file called CCs.res?

if so that line in your code should be  `{$R CCs.res}`

Comment: In that case he would get a compiler error message, but he gets an EResNotFound exception at runtime.